# SQL to calculate daily average for a column with records of some dates are missing

Tags: sql, oracle, math, average

I have table like below:

[image]

I have to calculate daily average count of session for each user.

First i calculated, total no of sessions for each day for every user and from that i tried to calculate average of daily session. I understand that it wont work since all users dont have sessions for every date.Some dates are missing for all users. Is there any way to calculate daily average when there is no entries for some dates

```sql
WITH daily_count AS
(
  SELECT user_id,  to_char(local_time,’MM/DD/YYYY’) AS Date, count(session_id) AS  total_count
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY device_id, to_char(local_time,’MM/DD/YYYY’)
)
SELECT user_id , AVG(total_count) AS average_session_count
FROM daily_count
GROUP BY user_id 

For eg: The max date in the above given table is Feb04 and the min date is Jan31 .So the total no of days is 5 days.If we take Userid 1, it is having records only for 2 dates. So the query i wrote will calculate average for 2 days not for 5 days. How to make it to calculate average for 5 days
```

Comment: What results do you want?  All your user have at most one session per day, so the average per day is "1".

Comment: so if for date `1,2,3` number of sessions for one user is`1,0(no sessions),5` then what output do you want in average sessions? --> `2 or 3`?

Answer (score 0):

if for date `1,2,3` number of sessions for one user is `1,0(no sessions),5` then what output do you want in average sessions? --> `2 or 3`?

You need to change your main query as follows:

```
SELECT USER_ID,
       AVG(TOTAL_COUNT) AS AVERAGE_SESSION_COUNT -- if you want output as 3 then use this
       --SUM(TOTAL_COUNT)/(MAX(DATE) - MIN(DATE) + 1) -- if you want output as 2 then use this
  FROM DAILY_COUNT
 GROUP BY USER_ID
```